# Changing localStorage Variables in Javascript through the Server

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I have a variable `localStorage.lastUpdate` which stores a timestamp such as `1332237161`. I need to pass that timestamp to the server which im trying to do by the line below with:

`listener.php?q="+localStorage.lastUpdate`

I also have another variable, `localStorage.numUpdates` that should receive the number of updates back from the server. I am confused whether I can use the below code with xml to run commands. Can my server side php file do something of the following

`echo "localStorage.numUpdates=".$currentCount.";";`

`echo "localStorage.lastUpdate=".time().";";`

where it would take affect on my localStorage variables in the javascript portion?

```
function contactServer()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","listener.php?q="+localStorage.lastUpdate,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Any information would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work (and don't use `eval()`!).

But you can just output JSON in your PHP script:

```
echo json_encode( array('lastUpdate' => time(), 'numUpdated' => $currentCount) );
```

And in your JavaScript code:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
  var result = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
  localStorage["lastUpdate"] = result["lastUpdate"];
  localStorage["numUpdated"] = result["numUpdated"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was of so much help!